# How to store data on apache server?

Tags: php, apache

I'm a php developer. In .NET we are able to store data in server in one variable.

It's possible that we can store one array in apache server's & get that?

I'm now using php_memcache.dll on my WAMP

```
$memcache_obj = memcache_connect('localhost',80);

memcache_set($memcache_obj, 'var_key', 'some variable', MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED , 0);

echo memcache_get($memcache_obj, 'var_key');
```

when i'm doing this memcache_set return false & gives warning

```
Notice: memcache_set() [function.memcache-set]: Server localhost (tcp 80) failed with: Failed reading line from stream (0) in abc file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding.

> It's possible that we can store one array in apache server's & get that?

Not in Apache, but in [`memcached`](http://www.memcached.org/) (it is also a server, aka "memory cache daemon" == memcached). 
Apache and memcached are different things. They co-exist.

> I'm now using php_memcache.dll on my WAMP

Okay, this is the client library for memcache. It provides you the `memcache_set()` and `memcache_get()` functions in PHP.

It does **not** automatically provide a memcache server. [Read here on how to setup memcache in a windows environment.](https://pureform.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/installing-memcache-on-windows-for-php/) Memcache is not originally developed to support windows, but there is a ported version of it.

Once set up correctly, you will need to change your first line:

```
$memcache_obj = memcache_connect('localhost',80);
```

Port 80 is HTTP, which is served by Apache - memcache runs on port 11211 in most default setups:

```
$memcache_obj = memcache_connect('localhost', 11211);
```

Answer (score 0):

In php5 it is possible to write to server variables (ie. $_SERVER['foo']), however it will be completely dropped at the next page request. For saving specific user variables, you can use the session_start() + $_SESSION methodology. Which, of course, will only work for that specific user. But to have a users actions set a variable; that can then be related to any other user on the site, without database storage, you'll need the usesage of applications such as [memcached](http://memcached.org/).